# htmlExpand (iframe) always centered

Tags: highslide

Bonjour,

For instance on [this url](http://www.obs43.fr), how to do that hs.htmlExpand() in the footer is **automatically "recentered"** when the "window" of **web browser is redimensioned**.
Now, the htmlExpand is only automatically centered (but fixed position) when opening.
Do you have an url which answers my question?
Merci.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will do what you want:

http://highslide.com/studies/window-resize.html

The example is using hs.align = 'auto', but the same code should work with hs.align = 'center'.